# How can I refresh a select option in a form without resulting loss of form input (Django + jQuery)

Tags: jquery, python, django, web

I have a form that has a dropdown list. However, a user can register a new value (into the database as well) by clicking a button next to it.

I managed to register it thru AJAX approach. However, I failed to find a way to refresh the dropdown list so that a user can select the newly inserted value.

I tried `location.reload(true)` but this will erase the existing form inputs. Is there a way for me to just refresh the dropdown list, or refresh without inputs loss?

My JQuery looks like this

```
$('#formSupplier').submit(function(e){
    $('#divProcessingMessage').show();
    $('#divSupplierForm').hide();
    $.post('/item/xhr_reg_supplier/',$('#formSupplier').serializeArray(),        
        function(data){
            if(data){
                alert('Supplier registration successful')
                $('#divProcessingMessage').hide();
                $('#divSupplierForm').show();

                //Clear the form's field
                $('#formSupplier').find(':input').each(function(){
                    switch(this.type) {
                        case 'password':
                        case 'select-multiple':
                        case 'select-one':
                        case 'text':
                        case 'textarea':
                            $(this).val('');
                            break;
                        case 'checkbox':
                        case 'radio':
                            this.checked = false;
                    } 
                });

                $('#supplier_form').hide();
                location.reload(true);
            } else {
                alert('Supplier registration failed')
            }        
        }
    );
```

I am using django 1.3.1 framework fyi.

Comment: why don't you redraw `select`, remove, update then create it again through Jquery!

Comment: @Ahsan uh..how? Sorry, I am new to JQuery ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

```
document.getElementById('form_id').reset()
```

or

```
$('#FormID').each (function(){
  this.reset();
});
```

or

```
jQuery.fn.reset = function () {
  $(this).each (function() { this.reset(); });
}

$("#FormID").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view that handles the AJAX request, have it re-render the form field & return the HTML. Then in the JS callback, swap it out with jquery: `$('select[name="thefield"]').replaceWith(data)`. You may need to re-bind events to the newly inserted DOM fragment, if there are page events that fire when the dropdown changes.